Who is in charge of reviewing edits and how can you obtain that role?
This may be a silly question, but I've noticed edits to posts are not automatically implemented, they have to be peer reviewed. It's a fair mechanism I like very much but don't know how it exactly works.
So, can you please explain who's in charge of the review and how you obtain this privilege? Is that the moderators (but the site doesn't have moderators, up to now..)?

When we were in private beta, some members from the SE team were monitoring and reviewing. But as users start to breach certain reputation thresholds, users themselves can review.

350+ users "access first posts and late answers review queues";
500+, can review close and reopen votes;
1000+ users can review suggested edits and low quality posts,
and so on

You can view more on the Privileges page (you can add privileges after the .com\ part for any SE sites, and it will show you your current position).
You can also, if you have more than 350+ rep, click on the review button above next to your reputation and see what other things you can do specifically about reviewing. Here is the button:


Fine, so the answer is: I need 1k reputation to review edits.

@martina At least, yes. :P

Alenanno's answer is correct, though those reputation thresholds will go up if the site graduates - but Italian won't have to worry about that for quite some time. (And when it comes time, one of the criteria we look at for graduation is "can this site survive the rise in reputation thresholds for privileges" anyway.)
Additionally, now that the site is in public beta, I will be selecting moderators pro tempore. These folks will have access to all review queues in addition to the moderator tools. 
